# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en un mismo botón, me ejecute dos acciones en Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Lo que necesito es que al hacer click en el botón "Resgitrar Pasaje", además de guardar el registro, debe imprimirme un pdf.

La acción "Store" lo hace muy bien, el problema es que no me ejecuta la acción "pasajeImpreso".

> Ambos por separado si funcionan.

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'generar/pasaje','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
{{Form::token()}}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="{{URL::action('PasajeController@pasajeImpreso')}}" target="_blank">
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar Pasaje</button>
    </a>
</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Esta es mi acción pasajeImpreso():

```
public function pasajeImpreso()
{
    $query = DB::table('pasajes as p')
                ->

    $view = \View::make('generar.pasaje.pasajeImpreso')->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    return $pdf->stream('Pasaje');
}
```

La ruta para la acción pasajeImpreso es este:

```
Route::get('pasaje_impreso', ['uses' => 'PasajeController@pasajeImpreso']);
```

> Para este cometido estoy usando el paquete barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: cual es tu ruta que te lleva a pasajeImpreso?

Comment: Ya actualizé la pregunta @LeviArista  :)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te arroja? ¿porque no llamas la función `pasajeImpreso()`, en el método `store` o viceversa? ya que no estas usando ningún `input`, no veo para que usar un `form`, podrías usar sólo el botón con la ruta que tienes definida y allí en el método para crear el pasaje, si necesitas el `id` del `user` solo inyectas el `request`

Comment: Hola @Camilo, no hay ningún error, pensé que los inputs ya estaban sobreentendidos, sólo necesito que el mismo botón que uso para llamar a la acción "Store", también me llame a la acción "pasajeImpreso" y el render de la página de pasajeImpreso.blade.php me lo muestre en un target="_blank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví, sólo tuve que colocar la propiedad onclick en el botón:

```
<button onclick="imprimir();" class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar Pasaje</button>
```

y posterior un script en la parte inferior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imprimir() {
    window.open('{{URL::action('PasajeController@pasajeImpreso')}}', '_blank');
};
</script>
```

el route es el mismo:

```
Route::get('pasaje_impreso', ['uses' => 'PasajeController@pasajeImpreso']);
```

=)

Comment: Pues eso te puse al principio XD, espera ah ya se porque no te funciono en mi respuesta, olvide poner las comillas :v

Comment: Es que me funcionó a la primera cuando la propiedad onclick lo puse directo sobre el botón :).... Pero me diste la idea @Levi, graciasssss  :)

Comment: De nada! No olvides marcar tu respuesta como correcta para que otros puedan saber que solucionaste tu consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Fácilmente podrías usar javascript para abrir tu pdf, así mandarías el request que registre el pasaje y a la vez generarías tu pasaje impreso.

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'generar/pasaje','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}

{{Form::token()}}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <span id="url_pasajeimpreso" hidden="">
         {{URL::action('PasajeController@pasajeImpreso')}
    </span>

    <a href="#" target="_blank" 
    //Aquí es donde llamas a tu pasaje impreso mediante javascript
    onclick="window.open(document.getElementById('url_pasajeimpreso').value, '_blank');">
         <button class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar Pasaje</button>
    </a>

</div>

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

---

**Solución alterna**

De esta forma llamarás a tu controlador donde guardarás tu registro y luego harás un redirect a la ruta de la otra acción (todo se renderizará en la misma página).

```
public function generarPasaje(Request $request){

    // Aquí incluyes todo el código que guarde el registro 
    // y en lugar de retornar la vista, 
    // retornas a la acción de generar tu pdf

    return redirect()->route('pasaje_impreso');   
}
```

Comment: En caso no funcione usa la ruta literal que usas para llamar a tu accion pasaje impreso

Comment: Hola @Levi, no funciona :(

Comment: XD ok, que te muestra en la etiqueta `<a>` si inspeccionas el codigo del navegador

Comment: Edite la pregunta con otra solucion, talvez te funcione

Comment: Hola @Levi Arista, y usando esa alternativa alterna, cómo hago para que me redireccione; pero a otra ventana (_blank)?

Comment: Esa es la desventaja de la segunda, pero en teoria la primera deberia funcionar, mira esta otra pregunta que respondi, tal vez te ayude tambien: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178460/enviar-formulario-con-ajax-en-laravel/178479?noredirect=1#comment335143_178479