# enviar formulario con ajax en laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Tengo un problema con el ajax que estoy utilizando, necesito enviar esas variable pero me aparece un error en consola, no encuentra la ruta y necesito saber como enviarlo por laravel obviamente

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{url("actualizar_baja")}}',
        data: {calibre:calibre, medio:medio, NCF:NCF, cantCD:cantCD, rango:rango, proteccion:proteccion, id:id, num:num},

        //funcion para retornar los resultados y mostrarlo en cada td
        success: function(resultado) {
             $('#tabla_ntc_2050_utilizar'+id).html(resultado.split("#")[1]);
        },
});
```

**Error en consola**

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST
>   disenos.test/Memories/2/%7B%7Burl()%7D%7D/actualizar_baja 404 (Not
>   Found)

Comment: ¿Que error te aparece en la consola?

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://disenos.test/Memories/2/%7B%7Burl()%7D%7D/actualizar_baja 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No puedes usar blade dentro de javascript**, pero puedes optar por esta solución, adicionalmente no estás enviando el **CSRF Token** en tu *post*.

Primero usa un `span` en el que almacenes tu ruta como texto:

```
<span id="url_actualizarbaja" hidden="">
     {{url("actualizar_baja")}}
</span>
```

Considera además guargar el token csrf en una etiqueta de la vista

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Luego llamas a esa ruta desde el texto del `span`, envía también el token csrf

```
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $("#url_actualizarbaja").text(),
        data: {
          _token: CSRF_TOKEN, //aquí considera el token csrf
          calibre:calibre, 
          medio:medio, 
          NCF:NCF, 
          cantCD:cantCD, 
          rango:rango, 
          proteccion:proteccion, 
          id:id, 
          num:num
        },

        //funcion para retornar los resultados y mostrarlo en cada td
        success: function(resultado) {
             $('#tabla_ntc_2050_utilizar'+id).html(resultado.split("#")[1]);
        },
});
```

Comment: tampoco funciono ahora sinplemente cambio el error

jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://disenos.test/actualizar_baja 419 (unknown status)

Comment: Eso se debe a que no estas enviando el token de seguridad de laravel en los headers, editare mi respuesta agregando eso

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciono!

Comment: Genial. Saludos